# Lookup over Multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel-formula

I have one Worksheet, with two tabs:

- Tab A has the following columns:  Name, ID Number
- Tab B has the following columns:  ID Number, Phone Number

On Tab A, I would like to add the Phone Number (from Tab B).

I have tried the following in Tab A, and get a #NA result.

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'Tab B'!A1:B400,'Tab B'!A:A,FALSE)
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The third criteria is the relative column number of the return value not a range.

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'Tab B'!A:B,2,FALSE)
```